# Connecting my iPod to my Car's 30-pin Dock but Being Able to Control It from Within the iPod?

Tags: ipod, dock, lightning, car-integration

I have a 5th Generation iPod nano. I own a 2008 VW Eos which has a 30-pin dock. It functions but, my car's UI for iPod is despicable. I wanted to know if there was a way to control the music within the iPod.

EDIT: My car does not have an AUX-in and, I'd rather don't go the FM transmitter route.

Comment: what does "nefastous" mean? Do they have a website if that is an app?

Comment: I think that he meant nefarious. I would say hideous. iPod nanos do not run app store apps.

Comment: LoL. I changed the word; hopefully it makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you can override the car's interface when using the 30-pin connector with that iPod.

If you use an aux cable (1/8" male to 1/8" male) to the headphone port you will be able to control the iPod using it's native interface, but you will lose the charging capability. To regain charging you could use a 12-volt power adaptor, but this is two cables instead of the single cable you are currently using.

Comment: Yeah. I'm aware of that but, unfortunately, my car does not have an AUX-in and I really don't want to go the FM transmitter route either. Thanks, though.

Comment: Cassette adaptor? My cars have had either a cassette or an aux in. I'm spoiled in my VW with aux in, 30 pin and Bluetooth.